# Theorem 2.4-3 in Kryszeg's *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications*

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

In the book, *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications* by Erwin Kreyszig, Theorem 2.4-3 states that every finite dimensional subspace $Y$ of a normed space $X$ is closed in $X$.

Now the author states the above result on the basis of Theorem 2.4-2 and Theorem 1.4-7. These theorems are as follows:

Theorem 1.4-7: A subspace $Y$ of a complete metric space $X$ is complete if and only if $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$.

Theorem 2.4-2: Every finite dimensional subspace $Y$ of a normed space $X$ is complete. In particular, every finite dimensional normed space is complete.

Now is Theorem 2.4-3 as stated by Kreyszig correct?

On the basis of Theorems 1.4-7 and 2.4-2, the statement of Theorem 2.4-3 should be one of the following:

1. Every finite dimensional subspace $Y$ of a Banach space $X$ is closed in $X$.

OR

2. Every subspace $Y$ of a finite dimensional normed space $X$ is closed in $X$.

Am I right?

And if so, then how to convince myself as to the correctness (or otherwise) of the statement given by Kreyszig in his Theorem 2.4-3?

Comment: Well, just prove it without appealing to too much machinery. Take a sequence in your finite-dimensional subspace and assume it is convergent. Does the limit belong to the subspace?

Comment: What is missing is that a complete subspace (in the topological sense) of any metric space is closed. [Generalise to complete subspaces of Hausdorff uniform spaces if desired.]

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, how to prove that a convergent sequence in our finite dimensional subspace $Y$ does converge in the subspace $Y$ itself?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I'm afraid I just didn't get your point. So could you please elaborate? If it's not too inconvenient for you, then please write out a detail answer to my original question in its specific context. That'd be so kind of you!

Comment: In first paragraph of proof of Theorem 1.4-7 it doesn't use the completeness of X.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do in the way you want

Let $Y$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $X$.Using theorem 2.4.2 $Y$ is complete.Now using theorem 1.4.7 $Y$ is closed.Thus you get theorem 2.4.3

Note:If we assume that $Y$ is complete and want to show that $Y$ is closed we dont require completeness of $X$

Comment: why don't we require completeness of $X$? How? Can you please give a complete proof of the following assertion? Let $(X,\vert\cdot\vert$ be a normed space, and let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$. Then $Y$ is closed.

Comment: Consider a sequence $x_n$ in $Y$ converging to some $x$ in $X$ Now $x_n$ is Cauchy and $Y$ is complete so it converges to some $y$ in $Y$ limit of a convergent sequence unique hence $x=y$ .got it!